# Remove tick on Bootstrap select with multiselect option

Tags: select

I have multi select box to which I am adding boostarp select plugin for styling, I want to remove tick i have tried options of boostarp select to remove it, But it doesn't seems like removing tick icon, I ended up `'data-tick-icon': ''` with this option, Is there any other way to remove tick icon on the left of the option

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, { start_year: 2000, end_year: Time.current.year + 50 }, multiple: true, class: 'bs-lg', id: 'incidentOccurredYears', 'data-style': 'form-control','data-tick-icon': '', 'data-actions-box':"true", 'data-live-search': 'true') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many different ways as well but it seems by simply adding the `data-tick-icon=""` to the `select` element will do the trick